# Synchronising across networked python apps

Tags: python-2.7, network-programming, synchronization

I am hoping this isn't too vague a question...

I am writing a python app that will have multiple instances of itself to allow load balancing and redundancy to take place.

Each instance will need to be able to read and write to the backend database, which raises the issue of two 'gateways' trying to update the same item.

Can anyone recommend an approach (not primarily looking for code solution) to this?

Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have mainly two ways to avoid loosing consistency on your data set:

- either use some lock mechanisms between the python processes,
- or use transactions when accessing the database.

Lock mechanisms must be based on inter-process communications. Depending on your underlying operating system, you may have access to shared memory (think about test-and-set primitive, to use shared memory for such a goal), semaphores and others tools. See Python IPC, for instance: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html

Transactions depend on your database. For instance, with a traditional SQL database, you can often configure the behaviours according to your needs: auto-commit, optimistic concurrency, etc...